# Laravel - retrieve direct/indirect pivot table subscribers

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I am having a hard time figuring this out in laravel; for a subscriber relationship we have 2 pivot tables:

A subscriber can subscribe to a question:

```
question_subscriber
id   question_id  subscriber_id
1        2            3
2        2            4
3        3            1
4        3            2
```

A subscriber can subscribe to a user:

```
user_subscriber
id  user_id  subscriber_id
1      1         6
2      1         7
3      2         1
```

Normal questions table with question owner:

```
questions
id  question  user_id
1     abc?       1
2     xyz?       1
3     123?       2
```

The pivot relationships are setup correctly in their models, and I can pull out with a foreach, subscribers for a question, `$question->subscribersQuestion as $subscriber`, or subscribers for a user, `$user->subscribersUser as $subscriber`:

But how can we pull out **all subscribers** that belong to a user (directly or indirectly (through a question they own))?

For example, these should be all retrieved subscribers for `user 1`:

```
6 // subscribed to directly
7 // subscribed to directly
3 // subscribed to through question
4 // subscribed to through question
```

Any idea on the most efficient way to do this in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the easiest way:

```php
// assuming this setup: 
User hasMany Question
User belongsToMany User (subscribers - direct)
Question belongsToMany User (subscribers - indirect)

// we don't need this, since we pass it by reference to the closure,
// but for clarity let's initialize this variable:
$indirectSubscribers = null;

$user = User::with(['questions.subscribers' => function ($q) use (&$indirectSubscribers) {
  // get all indirect subscribers (cost of additional query)
  $indirectSubscribers = $q->get()->unique();
}])->find($userId);

// merge with directs subscribers
$allSubscribers = $user->subscribers->merge($indirectSubscribers);
```

Comment: Hmmm.. can you explain the use (&..) and what that query syntax is doing? It works as you said, but adds an additional 4 queries. I am starting to think that it's best to maybe have them all in one table with a flag for user or question so querying/pagination/etc will be a lot easier. I am not sure if it's best to use a polymorphic relationship in this case for that and create a new model subscribers. Your thoughts and advice are very appreciated.

Comment: `&` means passing by [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) in order to write the variable inside the closure. This one doesn't add 4 queries, just 1 (`$q->get()` part). However in total there are 5 queries (user, user.subscribers, questions, questions.subscribers x 2). Not sure what query syntax you're refering to?

Comment: Got it - I don't fully understand how it's working; everything after $user = seems pretty confusing. By syntax I was referring to `['questions.subscribers' => function ($q) use (&$indirectSubscribers) {
  // get all indirect subscribers (cost of additional query)
  $indirectSubscribers = $q->get()->unique();
}])->find($userId)`

Comment: To paginate the 4 results into 2, this doesn't seem to work ->find($userId)->paginate(2); Is it not possible to paginate the results directly?

Comment: There's no way to paginate this the usual way, since you run 2 queries and merge the results. If you want to, then better create a db view and use Eloquent like with simple table.